# Webpack 4 - Dynamic Import can't set proper location

Tags: javascript, webpack

I am using Dynamic Import of Webpack 4. When I build my entry file(app.js), inside the main.bundle.js file the modules associated with it can't set it's(modules) location to 'dist/{another_module}'. It sets inside the root folder.

webpack.config.js

```
const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    main: "./src/app.js"
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
    filename: "[name].bundle.js",
    chunkFilename: "[name].bundle.js"
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader"
        }
      }
     ]
  }
};
```

src/app.js

```
function getScript() {
  return import(/* webpackChunkName: "script" */ "./script").then(res => {
    console.log(res.default);
  });
}

getScript();
```

src/script.js

```
export default function script() {
    console.log("script file is loaded")
}
```

.babelrc

```
{
  "plugins": ["@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import"]
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I found the answer, I just need to set `publicPath: "/dist/"`.
For more info - https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/7417